# NoClassDefFoundError when run a simple extent report configuration TestNG

Tags: java, testng, extentreports

I was trying to understand the working of ExtentReports and wrote 2 simple classes one where I am initializing the extent report variables and the test class where I am using, please see the below classes

```
package TestProperty;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter;
public class CheckReport {
    ExtentSparkReporter spark = new ExtentSparkReporter("C:\\Users\\jq2870\\eclipse-workspace\\TestJava Project\\Reports\\extentreports.html");
    protected ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports();

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() {
        extent.attachReporter(spark);
    }
}
```

and the class where I am using the report var is

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import TestProperty.CheckReport;


public class NewTest extends CheckReport{
    ExtentTest test = extent.createTest("CreateUser");
    @Test
    public void f() {
        test.info("This is a test class");

    }

}
```

and I am trying to run this by right click on the class and run and testNG test in eclipse but getting this issue

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.2.0
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class NewTest
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:30)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.instantiateUsingDefaultConstructor(InstanceCreator.java:193)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstanceUsingObjectFactory(InstanceCreator.java:113)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstance(InstanceCreator.java:79)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:109)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:167)
    at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:102)
    at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:82)
    at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:74)
    at org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:39)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:460)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:339)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:292)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:223)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:33)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:66)
    at org.testng.ITestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(ITestRunnerFactory.java:55)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:676)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:178)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1302)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1278)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1127)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1066)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1034)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:23)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: freemarker/template/TemplateModelException
    at TestProperty.CheckReport.<init>(CheckReport.java:9)
    at NewTest.<init>(NewTest.java:6)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: freemarker.template.TemplateModelException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 35 more
```

Can anyone tell me why this error is coming?

Comment: If your  ExtentReports version is lower than 5 check the relevant freemarker version (and other dependencies)

Comment: @abhinav is this the full code in `NewTest` and `CheckReport` ?

Comment: @GauthamM yes this is the complete class that I have pasted.

Comment: @user7294900 extent report version is 5.0.1 and freemarker version I am using is 2.3.31

Comment: @AbhinavKumarMall I was asking to confirm if there were any parameterized constructors. the exception seemed like that is the case

Comment: @GauthamM no there are none, I haven't created any constructor of my own, just these two classes. Also when I am removing the extent reports objects I am able to run the class so seems like something wrong with the extent report. or something I am doing out of ordinary which is giving the exception but I am not able to figure thi out.

Answer (score 1):

[ExtentReports](https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-java/blob/master/pom.xml) include also FreeMarker jar that you need to have in classpath

> ```
> <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
>       <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
>       <version>2.3.30</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

Comment: added the JAR but still getting the issue